# Receiving error: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: list, arguments

I am receiving the error:

> actual and formal argument lists differ in length

However; the Login class is configured to only two strings?
Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

This is my code:

```
/**
 *
 * @author vince
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Attempt to Login
        System.out.println(login("username","password"));
    }

    private static LoginResponse login(Login authParameters) throws DispatchServiceFault {
        client.DispatchService_Service service = new client.DispatchService_Service();
        client.DispatchService port = service.getDispatchServicePort();
        return port.login(authParameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add the language you're using as a tag. (I'm unsure if it's Java or C#...).

Comment: When asking a language-specific question, always add a language tag in addition to any others. It makes the question more clear and gets it in front of the people who can answer it more quickly.